# How to compare two XmlNodes of XmlDocument in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode, deepequals

This is a sample xml. If a new font is to be added in the sense, all the existing fonts to be compare with the new font before adding to the preference.
How do I check the node(font) whether already exists or not in case of XmlDocument?

```
<preferences>
  <font role="console">
    <size>9</size>
    <fname>Courier</fname>
  </font>
  <font role="default">
    <fname>Times New Roman</fname>
    <size>14</size>
  </font>
  <font role="titles">
    <size>10</size>
    <fname>Helvetica</fname>
  </font>
</preferences>
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask your question. Can you edit your post to make it more clear what you're asking? I think what you're looking for is the `XDocument` class.

Comment: @JamieTwells: it's on the title of the question, it just requires some editing. I would retract any flag if you did so ;-)

Comment: @JamieTwells thanks for the concern.

Comment: @JamieTwells I was exactly looking for XmlDocument.

Comment: See this article [Equality Semantics of LINQ to XML Trees](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2009/01/27/equality-semantics-of-linq-to-xml-trees/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to create a couple of classes to represent the XML document and implement the `IEquatable<T> Interface`.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/QZFwDy

**Classes for XML**

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "font")]
public class Font : IEquatable<Font>
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "size")]
    public string Size { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "fname")]
    public string Fname { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "role")]
    public string Role { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Font font)
    {
        if (font == null) return false;

        return (Size == font.Size) && (Fname == font.Fname) && (Role == font.Role);
    }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "preferences")]
public class Preferences
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "font")]
    public List<Font> Font { get; set; }
}
```

Then use the `Preferences` class to deserialize the XML. Once the document is deserialized, leverage the `List<T>.Contains(T item)` method to see if the font node exists. The `.Contains` method will call the implementation of `Equals` in the `Font` class.

**Code to Demonstrate**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Preferences preferences = null;
    var xmlString = Data.XML;

    using (var stream = new StringReader(xmlString))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Preferences));
        preferences = (Preferences)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }

    var node0 = new Font()
    {
        Fname = "New One",
        Role = "console",
        Size = "12"
    };

    var node1 = new Font()
    {
        Fname = "Helvetica",
        Role = "titles",
        Size = "10"
    };

    if (preferences.Font.Contains(node0))
    {
        // Not expecting to enter here
        Console.WriteLine($"'{nameof(node0)}' is already present");
    }

    if (preferences.Font.Contains(node1))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"'{nameof(node1)}' is already present");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Xnode has a feature called DeepEqual to compare nodes. XmlNode can be converted into Xnode by simple parsing.

```
    XElement XmlElementToXElement(XmlNode e)
    {
        return XElement.Parse(e.OuterXml);
    }
```

So, it will be easier from here. The method below will return true if two nodes are equal.

```
    bool XmlNode_DeepEquals(XmlNode node1, XmlNode node2)
    {
        XElement tempX = XmlElementToXElement(node2);
        XElement searchX = XmlElementToXElement(node1);
        return XNode.DeepEquals(tempX, searchX))
    }
```

This method is for comparing a list of Node.

```
    bool isNodeAlreadyExists(XmlNode searchNode, XmlNodeList list)
    {
        bool exists = false;
        foreach (XmlNode node in list)
        {
            if (XmlNode_DeepEquals(searchNode, node))
            {
                exists = true;
            }
        }
        return exists;
    }
```

Comment: `DeepEquals` does not take into account the order of the nodes. See [Equality Semantics of LINQ to XML Trees](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2009/01/27/equality-semantics-of-linq-to-xml-trees/).